# Populate value for new column based on other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2016, It has 3 columns, (Id,Month,Year) now I want to add a new column to the existing table and its value should be populated based on the Month and Year column's value for existing records and even for new records which are inserted later.

Expected output:

```
Id  Month       Year      Del_Range
------------------------------------
1   January     2020      2020-01-01
2   February    2020      2020-02-01
3   March       2020      2020-03-01
```

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb..#test
(
    Id int,
    [Month] varchar(50),
    [Year] int,
)
GO

INSERT INTO tempdb..#test (Id, [Month], [Year])
VALUES (1, 'January', 2020), 
       (2, 'February', 2020), 
       (3, 'March', '2020')
GO

SELECT * FROM tempdb..#test
GO

ALTER TABLE tempdb..#test
    ADD Del_Range DATE
-- Need to add logic to populate value for this column based on value from Month and Year to get expected output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this below query

```
alter table #test add Del_Range as convert(date, concat([year], [month], id)) 

insert into #test(id, month, year)
select 4, 'april', 2020
union 
select 4, 'May', 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command.

```
alter table #test add Del_Range as cast(cast(Year as varchar(4)) + Month + '01' as date)--for first day for a month
```